# Is Kaivalya only way for Soul to go back to it's original nature of infinity?

Tags: moksha, kaivalya

We have four types of Moksha - Salokya, Sarupya Samipya and finally Kaivalya.
Even in Yoga tattva upanishad - Lord Vishnu talks about Kaivalya Moksha is the way to be free from influence of Maya.

So my question is this: Does Kaivalya Moksha alone grant the soul to become absorbed in Parabrahman? Then what about other Mokshas? If that's the case, Is there a chance of falling to this world again in other Mokshas?

Comment: These 4 types of Moksha are as per which branch of Vaishnavism? On [this site](https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/There_are_five_kinds_of_liberation:_salokya,_samipya,_sarupya,_sarsti_and_sayujya), 5 types of liberation is mentioned.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria It was Rama-Hanuman conversation in upanishads.

Comment: So 4 types of liberation is not accepted by any branch of Vaishnavism even though Sri Rama said it?

Comment: I do not know that which branch of Vaishnavism said it. But my question is - is there falling of the soul from state of Moksha if it's not Kaivalya? If you're in loka of deities - is it sill considered Moksha? When I say deities - Vishnu, Kailash, and Shivaloka. (I am talking about Vishnu among Tridev and not Maha Vishnu)

Comment: No. The focus of this question is different ! That question defines Kaivalya Moksha. The focus of this question is - is Kaivalya the only way and nature of other Mokshas. There's difference in it!

Comment: In that question, you have mentioned the discussion between Sri Rama and Hanuman, Sri Rama is saying Kaivalya Moksha is ultimate and the answer says the same thing.

Comment: I am not asking which Moksha is ultimate. My question is if Kaivalya Moksha is only way, then what about other Mokshas. Will a soul fall down in other Mokshas ? Then in that case, what happens to those lokas.

Comment: I have made it clear here:  But my question is - is there falling of the soul from state of Moksha if it's not Kaivalya? If you're in loka of deities - is it sill considered Moksha?

Comment: Ok, you may be interested in Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, he has mentioned who can return to the world even after attaining the absolute state or knowledge, he described the absolute as Nitya and the world as Lila but added that only a few can stay in the world for the welfare of others after going into Samadhi. Ordinary beings after experiencing Samadhi cannot live longer than 21 days. The beings who can stay in the world even after attaining knowledge are known as Isvarakotis. Sri Ramakrishna, sage Narada, Chaitanya are few of the examples.

Comment: I wouldn't call them types but rather stages.

Comment: Aishwaryarthi , Kaivalyarthi , Bhagavad-labharthi - are the 3 types of yearners - those who want material wealth on earth/heaven upto satya-lok are aishwaryarthi. those who don't want material wealth, but just want to enjoy their own atma by themselves - kaivalyarthi (kevalam means alone). those who want to serve & enjoy paramatma vaikuntapathi Vishnu - bhagavad-labharthi. kaivalyam - still chance of return, if you think your own atma enjoyment is higher than bhagavad guna enjoyment, you'll be enticed by bhagavan's guna (not maya). vaikunta (parama-padam) - no return.

Comment: In Kaivalya there seems to be another. One whose consciousness united with Paramatma and no difference between meditator and object of meditation,  then he is liberated to eternal bliss of God. So is my thinking correct? Beyond all types of Moksha, God is ultimate? @ram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes among the various kinds of liberation viz- SAlokya, SArshti, SAyujya etc only Kaivalya (also known as NIrvAna Mukti) is eternal in nature.

In this context the Tantrik compendium ["ShAktAnanda Tarangini"](http://www.shivashakti.com/shaktanan.htm) quotes the following verse in the 16th Chapter of the text:

> SakAmAnAm sAyujyAdi muktih sAyujyam na parA muktih sharira samvandhAt
>   |
>  AkAmAnAm nirvAnameva muktih parama purushArthatvAt || "Na cha
>   punarAvartate " --- Iti sruteh ||
>
> The Mukti that desirous persons (sakAma) get are Sayujya etc. SAyujya is
>   not the eternal or highest form of liberation. Because, [in it]
>   association with the body is still there. The desireless persons
>   (NishkAma) get NirvAna Mukti. Which is the highest goal and even in
>   Sruti it is stated -  [He or the liberated being] does not return.

So, the highest form of Mukti, after attaining which one does not return, is not SAyujya and other forms of liberation. It is only the Kaivalya or the NirvAna Mukti.

Comment: what about devotees in Vaikuntha or Shivaloka? Is it eternal or not?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I am not sure what kind of Mukti leads one to Shivaloka/Vishnuloka. But if it's Kaivalya only then there will be no return otherwise there is return.

Comment: Are the Sayijya, Ekatva and Kaivalya different?

Comment: Yes, as per my answer Kaivalya is different from Sayujya Mukti. Kaivalya is the Para Mukti. @Pandya

Comment: Have just ordered Kaivalya from Amazon. It has been dispatched to its delivery.  Very excited.  @_@

Comment: It's kinda confusing that Madhusūdana Sarasvatī considered sāyujya mukti to be parāmukti and sālokya, sārūpya, etc. as aparāmukti. He also strongly argued that there's no tāratamya in parā mukti, but in aparā mukti, there's no problem in their being tāratamya.

Comment: Madhūsūdana Sarasvatī does consider sāyujya to be ekatva. But I am not sure, if he sees it equal to kaivalya or not.

Comment: I see ... @Bingming